# How can i make my layout resize proportionally as screen size changes?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have 9 rows and 6 columns of buttons so i was using this code to change size of each button proportionally:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    int Orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    if(Orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(height/10,width/7));
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(height/10,width/7));
        Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(height/10,width/7));
        Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btn4.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(height/10,width/7
```

But this does not work size of buttons changes but they do not fit well. Beow is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/ResultText"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="#AAAAAA"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/InputText"
    android:background="#BBBBBB"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" />


</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/memoryStatText"
    android:background="#BBBBBB"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMAdd"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="M+"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill"/>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMRemove"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="M-"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMC"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="MC"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput"
    android:gravity="fill" />
```

In every case layout stretches horizontally perfectly on all devices, on larger devices however, lot of space remains vacant on bottom part of application. To just change height i changed my code to this:

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn1.setHeight(height/10));
```

But this reduces width of button for no reason.What am i doing wrong.My question basically is can i make my layout fit vertically as well as it fits horizontally.

Here are my images in two cases:[image]

Here is my second image:
[image]

Comment: try a custom ViewGroup to layout your children

Comment: I am a newbie and don't know how that would work, can you end me a link to some tutorial that is easy to follow.

Comment: google for: custom viewgroup

Comment: Is there any other way, i was thinking to consider creating custom view groups later after i have created three or four applications.

Comment: i dont know better one

Comment: Can you give me a hint how should i start.

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621107/how-can-i-make-complex-tablelayout-layout-android/17621361#17621361

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your TableLayout height to `match_parent`:

```
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:stretchColumns="*">
```

And make sure you remove the code based on orientation you have.

Comment: Columns fit perfectly the problem is with height of rows.